# What if the derivative of a function is positive for some range and negative for some other range?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ whose derivative is positive for some range ($x<x_1$) while it becomes negative for $x>x_1$. Can I say that the function is concave and the maximum is achieved at $x=x_1$? Or there is some mistake in this reasoning?

Comment: Is the function continuous?  Is the derivative continuous?

Comment: @DougM yes the function is continous

Comment: @DougM yes the derivative is also continuous.

Comment: @DougM a very simple example is given in the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522448/related-to-the-concavity-of-the-product-of-two-functions

Comment: The continuity of the function and its derivative are necessary conditions before you can jump to your conclusion.

Comment: @DougM yes that's right. But if the function is $\frac{1}{(a+bx^{-m})(c+dx^m)}$ where $0<m<1$ then I think the function and its derivative are both continuous for $x>0$. But the problem is that it is difficult to show through double derivative test that the function is concave or not. On the other hand looking at the expression for derivative of function, I think, the function first increases and then decreases and hence is a concave function.

Comment: @DougM Actually the double derivative maybe positive for some range of $x$. So, the confusion is that if we look at the derivative the function appears to be concave on the other hand if we look at the double derivative we cannot say such a thing.

Comment: The PDF of the guassian distribution has this property and is not concave. You may want to look into quasiconvexity.

Answer (score 0):

Can I say that the function is concave?

No. You can say it is [quasiconcave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function). For example the PDF of the normal distribution is not concave but it has positive derivative for $x < x_1$ and negative derivative for $x > x_1$ (where $x_1$ is the mean).

Is the maximum achieved at $x = x_1$?

Yes as was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522554/is-it-the-right-way-to-find-the-maximum-of-a-function-simple-query).

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable when $x\neq x_1$, and if $f'$ has opposite signs on each side of $x_1$, then $x=x_1$ does give the global maximum of $f$.

But $f$ does not have to be concave. It does not even have to be *locally* concave, in some small neighborhood around $x=x_1$.

Consider, for example,

$$f(x)=-\sqrt{|x|}$$

at $x=0$.

However, if $f$ is also differentiable at $x_1$, then $f'(x_1)$ must be zero. Now it must be the case that $f$ is *locally* concave, but $f$ does not have to be globally concave, as the example of the PDF of the normal distribution illustrates.